# Efficient element wise comparison between a pandas frame and a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, vectorization

Suppose that I have 2 objects:

- `A` is a list of names
- `B` is a pandas frame with 3 columns: 'name','friend1','friend2', which list a person's name and the names of their 2 best friends

For my application, I would like to know: for each person in `A`, a list of people in `B` for which the person in `A` is among the 2 best friends. To be specific, for each person in `A`, I would like a list `my_bool`  of booleans that can be computed as follows:

```
for current_name in A:
    my_bool = (B['friend1'] == current_name) | (B['friend2'] == current_name)
    [ ... other computation using my_bool ... ]
```

The computation works, but I'm trying to improve on its efficiency. For example, when A has length 15k and B has 50k rows, the computation time is very long.

My tuition is that: it's not efficient that the loop scans through the 50k rows of `B` for each person in `A`. Is there a way to vectorize the computation to create, say, a 15k x 50k matrix `all_bools` in 1 shot (without loop), then read off `my_bool` (as the rows of `all_bools`) later as needed? In another language, I can implement this idea, but I'm unable to do it in Python. If this idea is garbage too, please feel free to put forth your suggestion.

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset along with an expected output so that others can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

A = np.array(['Bob', 'Becky', 'Mark', 'Joe', 'Zeke'])
B = pd.DataFrame([['Joe', 'Mark', 'Bob'], ['Becky', 'Joe', 'Bob'], ['Mark', 'Tom', 'Trisha']], columns=['name', 'friend1', 'friend2'])

# resulting shape is (len(A), len(B.friend1))
friend1 = np.equal(A.reshape(-1, 1), B.friend1.values)
friend2 = np.equal(A.reshape(-1, 1), B.friend2.values)

# your final all_bools for later reference
all_bools = friend1 | friend2

# processing one at a time:
for i in range(all_bools.shape[0]):
    my_bool = all_bools[i]
    in_friends = B.loc[my_bool, 'name'].values
    if in_friends.any():
        print(f'My name is {A[i]} and Im friends with {in_friends}')
```

Given that it's numpy it is highly vectorized and efficient.
However... the downside to creating the array of `all_bools` all in one go is that there is a very good chance it will consume a lot of memory to store it.

**EDIT - since I don't have enough rep to comment** 

Clarification on reshaping: as per the docs on [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), it changes the shape of an array without changing the underlying data.
For an example:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>A = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>>A.shape

# one dimensional array of length 6
(6, )

>>>A.reshape(-1, 1).shape

# 2 dimensional array of 6 rows and 1 column
(6, 1)

>>>A.reshape(1, -1).shape
# 2 dimensional array of 1 row and 6 columns
(1, 6)

>>>A.reshape(2, 3)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Basically what reshape does is massage the array into the new desired shape (ie num rows by num cols) if possible. So in the above example, you can reshape the array into a 6x1 2d array, a 1x6 2d array, a 2x3 2d array etc.
If you try and reshape into an incompatible shape, you get an error:

```
>>> A.reshape(2, 4)                                                                                                     Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6 into shape (2,4)
```

`-1` acts sort of like a wildcard for one of the dimensions. Per the docs:

> One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

So we can do something like the following:

```
>>> A.reshape(3, -1).shape
(3, 2)
```

numpy infers that we need 2 columns to achieve a reshape of an array of size 6 into a 2d array with 3 rows.

As for why we need to reshape the arrays in your question, the short answer is because A and B are of different shapes, and numpy will complain if you try to compare them directly.

```
>>> B = np.arange(0, 10)
>>> np.equal(A, B)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (10,)
```

A and B can't be compared directly because they can't be broadcast against each other. Broadcasting is sort of a rabbit hole, probably worth reading the docs directly [link to docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

If we reshape A into a nrows x 1 column 2d array, we can broadcast B against it, resulting in every row of A being compared to every value in B

```
>>> np.equal(A.reshape(-1, 1), B).shape
(6, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is exactly what I wanted! Can you clarify something behind the magic: I do `A.shape` and get `(5,)`, whereas if I do `A.reshape(-1,1).shape` and get `(5,1)`. What is the difference and why do we need `A.reshape(-1,1)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) method, which implicitly converts the list to a hash map with a more efficient look-up time.

```py
my_bool = B['friend1'].isin(A) | B['friend2'].isin(B)
```